# How to get only matched data from nested class using query builder in elastic search?

Tags: spring-data-elasticsearch

I am trying to get only the matched data from nested array of elastic search class. but I am not able to get it..the whole nested array data is being returned as output.

this is my Query:-

QueryBuilders.nestedQuery("questions",
QueryBuilders.boolQuery()
.must(QueryBuilders.matchQuery("questions.questionTypeId", quesTypeId)), ScoreMode.None)
.innerHit(new InnerHitBuilder());

I am using querybuilders to get data from nested class.Its working fine but not able to get only the matched data.

Request Body :
{
"questionTypeId" : "MCMC"
}

when questionTypeId = "MCMC"
this is the output i am getting..Here I want to exclude the output for which the questionTypeId = "SCMC".

output :

```
   {
    "id": "46",
    "subjectId": 1,
    "topicId": 1,
    "subtopicId": 1,
    "languageId": 1,
    "difficultyId": 4,
    "isConceptual": false,
    "examCatId": 3,
    "examId": 1,
    "usedIn": 1,

    "questions": [
        {
            "id": "46_31",
            "pid": 31,
            "questionId": "QID41336691",
            "childId": "CID1",
            "questionTypeId": "MCMC",
            "instruction": "This is a single correct multiple choice question.",
            "question": "Who holds the most english premier league titles?",
            "solution": "Manchester United",
            "status": 1000,
            "questionTranslation": []
        },

        {
            "id": "46_33",
            "pid": 33,
            "questionId": "QID41336677",
            "childId": "CID1",
            "questionTypeId": "SCMC",
            "instruction": "This is a single correct multiple choice question.",
            "question": "Who holds the most english premier league titles?",
            "solution": "Manchester United",
            "status": 1000,
            "questionTranslation": []
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As you have tagged this with [spring-data-elasticsearch](/questions/tagged/spring-data-elasticsearch):

Support to return inner hits was recently added to version 4.1.M1 and so will be included in the next released version. Then in a `SearchHit` you will get the complete top level document, but in the `innerHits` property only the matching inner hits will be returned.

Comment: How do I get inner hit data? Even if I include  innerHit(new InnerHitBuilder()) this statement, I am getting top level document and not the matched inner hit data.

Comment: which version of Spring Data Elasticsearch do you use?

Comment: I am using -> spring-boot-starter-data-elasticsearch-2.2.6.RELEASE.jar and elasticsearch-core-6.8.7.jar

Comment: as I wrote, inner hits are returned in the `SearchHits` object in the next version 4.1. Spring Boot 2.2.x uses Spring Data Elasticsearch 3.2.x; in that version there is no support for that, you'd need to do your own response parsing there.