# How to build a search query with filtering for nested objects in spring-data elastic search?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-mvc, elasticsearch, spring-data, spring-data-elasticsearch

My Document is like:

```
class Foo{
 private Integer idDl;
 private String Name;
 private String Add;
 @Field(type = FieldType.Nested)
 private List< Bar> Bar;
 }
 
 class Bar{
 private Integer barId;
 private List<String> barData
 }
```

and `Foo` sample data is like:

```
{
    "idDl": 123,
    "Name": "ABCD",
    "Add": "FL",
    "Bar": [
        {
            "barId": 456,
            "barData": [
                "Bar1",
                "Bar2"
            ]
        },
        {
            "barId": 985,
            "barData": [
                "Bar4",
                "Bar5"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

I want to return all `Foo`objects where `Bar.barId` is matching but as `Bar` is list object in `Foo`, `Foo` must only contain only one `Bar` object who's id is matching with the id provided by user.I am using `NativeSearchQueryBuilder` provided by spring-data-elasticsearch as:

```
String[] includeFields = new String[]{"idDl", "Name"};
String[] excludeFields = new String[]{"Add"}; // to exclude Add field of Foo
Query searchQuery = new NativeSearchQueryBuilder()
            .withQuery(matchQuery("Bar.barId", 456))
            //.withQuery(termQuery("Bar.barId", 456))
            .withSourceFilter(new FetchSourceFilter(includeFields, excludeFields))
            .build();
return elasticsearchRestTemplate.queryForList( searchQuery, Foo.class);
```

The response I am getting consist of all `Bar` objects irrespective of Id, here is the sample response:

```
[
    {
        "idDl": 123,
        "Name": "ABCD",
        "Add": "FL",
        "Bar": [
            {
                "barId": 456,
                "barData": [
                    "Bar1",
                    "Bar2"
                ]
            },
            {
                "barId": 985,
                "barData": [
                    "Bar4",
                    "Bar5"
                ]
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "idDl": 758,
        "Name": "PQR",
        "Add": "NY",
        "Bar": [
            {
                "barId": 456,
                "barData": [
                    "Bar1",
                    "Bar2"
                ]
            },
            {
                "barId": 671,
                "barData": [
                    "Bar24",
                    "Bar25"
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

I tried using `termQuery` as commented in the snippet but i ain't getting response for it and for `matchQuery` I am getting response as above. In the response the `Bar` must contain only objects having the id 456 i.e. Id being sent in query. Any suggestions will be helpful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are querying for `Foo` objects where the exists a `Bar` that matches the criteria and Elasticsearch returns these `Foo`s. If you want to have the only the `Bar`s that matched, you need to add inner_hits to your query.

Check [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62862490) and answer for how to retrieve these, retrieving inner hits with Spring Data Elasticsearch will come with version 4.1.